Validity of the general solution to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2-bx}dx$
I was looking for a general solution to use as shortcuts, and I got the answer online but I don't know what $a$ and $b$ can be so that this is true:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2-bx}dx=e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$
I was wondering if for example we could have complex numbers like $a=i$ or $b=-i$ of some type, I know the solution of this comes from:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2-bx}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x^2+bx/a)}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x+bx/a)^2+\frac{b^2}{4a}}dx=e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ay^2}dy=e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$
But I don't know what types of conditions do I have to apply to $a$ and $b$ so I can use this anytime, including complex numbers. Maybe I could figure out that necessarily $a>0$, but is there anything else?

Think about Laplace transform kernel $e^{-st}$ by just checking the $\Re{s}>0$ and $t>0^+$.

$\operatorname{Re}(a) >0$ and $b\in\mathbb C$ is sufficient.
